# IntelliJ IDEA code inspection - external usages of - taking so long

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I run Analyze -> Inspect code. But it runs so long - for few hours. Most of the time (i think about 99%) progress bar says 'Processing external usages of xxx' where xxx stands for I guess, some getter/setters or fields. I would like to ask what this exactly do, what is a result of this long process, and how to disable this.

Answer (score 2):

"Inspect Code" is static code analysis. It tries to detect some simple bugs and other issues in your code without running it. Basically, it need to go through all your source codes. If you have lots of codes, it may take a long time to finish this task. So select the inspection scope carefully. Please check the following link for details of Code Inspections & Fixes.

[Code Inspections & Fixes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-inspection.html)

There are some inspection settings may cause idea print "Processing external usages of" message. The most common is "Unused declaration". If it is checked, idea is trying to search if any other class is using a declared symbol, such as, a class, a field or a method. It will prompt a warning if a symbol is not used at all. So it may take a long time if you have a large code base. Maybe you can uncheck it if it is useless for you.

Comment: I generally know how this inspect code works - I just would like to know what this 'external usage' stuff does and why it takes so long - maybe its some particular inspection I don't really need?

Comment: @M4ks I guess "external usage" means idea is trying to search if any other class is using a declared symbol, such as, a class, a field or a method. It will prompt a warning if a symbol is not used at all. Maybe you can uncheck "Unused declaration" in inspections configuration.

Comment: This is still valid in PhpStorm 2019.1.2. I had _Unused declaration_ inspection enabled, which caused the inspections running for very long time, reporting low memory. After disabling the inspection (i.e., all _Unused_ inspections disabled), everything goes fast.

Comment: I can confirm that disabling all the "Unused" inspections increases the speed of code inspection a lot in PhpStorm 2019.3.